# how do i make the background image fit perfectly using css/html?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm a newbie on HTML and CSS. How do I make the background image go all the way up and take up the white space at top and the sides as well? However, I'm not planning to make this image as a background for the entire page as I'd want to have multiple background images.

This is my code - CSS:

```
header
{
    background-image:linear gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url("background3.jpg");
    height:100vh;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFmgn.jpg)

Comment: i would inspect with devtools and figure out if the user-agent stylesheet is applying any margin on the body. also if you provide a full example on JSbin/JsFiddle/Codepen I could find out what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Would look into this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/.

Hope this helps.

### Update:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
     <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="Paris">
</div>
```

**CSS**

The image is absolute positioned so that the object-fit attribute can modify the width/height of the image based on the containers width and height:

```
.image {
  width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}

img {
    -o-object-fit:cover;
    object-fit:cover;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

I've created a fiddle shows this as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr7h76eh/1/.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18556077)

Comment: Sorry, completely understand so I have added a fiddle as an example.

Comment: This is much better and the edit is a clear improvement. Hopefully the downvotes will be reversed now